# how to use multiple arrays in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I have items in mongo database as the following:

```
"_id":01, "category": "Electronics", "type": "Television", price:345.00
"_id":02, "category": "Electronics", "type": "Mobile", price:145.00
"_id":03, "category": "Electronics", "type": "ipad", price:300.00
```

I am using Node.js express and jade to output the "category" and "type"

I have a find method in index.js to find all the documents in a collection.

```
/* GET Electronics page. */
router.get('/electronics', function(req, res) {
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('website');
collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
    res.render('electronics', {
        "electronics" : docs
        });
    });
});
```

I am able to print "type" field for all the documents first and then "price" field for all the documents using jade

```
for type in electronics
            a(href="/beauty")=type.type
for price in electronics
            a(href="/beauty")=price.price
```

output of the above code is something like:

```
Television
Mobile
ipad
345.00
145.00
300.00
```

I want to print for every "type" it should print its corresponding "type".
something like

```
Television 345.00
mobile 145.00
ipad 300.00
```

Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
for item in electronics
        a(href="/beauty")=item.type 
        a(href="/beauty")=item.price
        br
```

Comment: Can you let me know what does "item" here mean?

Comment: just last final question..
how do i print in next line?

it prints something like this...

Television 345.00mobile 145.00ipad 300.00